# What is the difference between grails run on server and grails run-app

Tags: grails

What is the difference between grails run on server and rails run-app, is run-app will project  run using server?? And I used Java 1.7 version for grails 2.1.1 will it work properly with java 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run-app is for development only. It runs the application in an embedded container. See the grails documentation of [run-app](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.0/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html).

Java 7 is ok if you upgrade to the latest 2.1.x patch level. Otherwise you may hit this one [GRAILS-10183](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10183).